# Is there a newer version than 1.2.5 for tomcat taglibs stanard jar

Tags: tomcat

I'm migrating Tomcat to 10.0 and looking for a suitable taglibs jar version, I only can find the latest jar version 1.2.5 from here https://tomcat.apache.org/download-taglibs.cgi, but it doesn’t work for tomcat 10.0.
From GitHub source code (https://github.com/apache/tomcat-taglibs-standard), I found there are a lot of changes after 1.2.5, but cannot find out a jar that includes the latest changes, anyone please give me some suggestions? Where can I download the latest jar (taglibs-standard-jstlel-xx.jar)? is current project retired? if yes, anyone knows the replaced one?

Looking for the latest taglibs-standard-xx-xx.jar that includes the latest changes.

Answer (score 0):

There has been no official release of tomcat-taglibs-standard since 1.2.5.

There was a "release candidate" tagged for 1.2.6 but there was never a VOTE for it, therefore there is no official release.

[Tomcat 10.0 reached EOL](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-eol.html) on 2022-10-31 and should not be used. You should use Tomcat 10.1 instead.

Tomcat 10.1 includes the capability to migrate an application from certain `javax.*` APIs to the equivalent `jakarta.*` APIs. You could use this auto-migration capability on your own application to migrate the taglib library to the new API which should work.

Another option would be to use the [standalone migration tool](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-migration.cgi) to migrate just the taglib libraries themselves separately, then bundle that into your application. The mechanism is the same for the two techniques (auto-migrate versus manual-migrate) but the result is the same: you should have a taglib implementation that will work in a Jakarta EE container.